# Super key is stuck for all users even after restart

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I recently tried to slightly change my key mapping (only add 2 dead keys for ˇ and ´ symbols) following [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions).

After I wrote the modification to the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` file, I did something (maybe by executing `sudo rm /var/lib/xkb/*.xkm`) and now my laptop behaves like the "Super key" is always pressed. E.g. 'H' key hides the opened window e.t.c. This is for all users and even after a restart the computer. Fortunately keyboard is working for disk decryption and login.

I have read and tried all solutions I have found here, I reinstalled language packages, executed `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data`, but nothing worked.

Thanks for any solutions.

Comment: Try: `sudo apt install --reinstall xkb-data`

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work either :/ How ever, I've managed to solve it by simply removing the part I added to ``/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`` file. I think I messed up some of the key binding in there.

Comment: The command I proposed restores the file to its original state, so it should have the same effect.